# Create MongoDB server in Node.js and use it with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to create and initiate a MongoDB server and a DB inside Node.JS and use Mongoose with that MongoDB server? I want to rent a VPS and use it with Node.JS, but I don't know how to run a Node.JS and MongoDB server at the same time in a VPS. I only have used MongoDB and Node.JS in my mac.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: If you're using node.js, you can use npm to install the mongoDB and mongoose packages You need to check with your host to see if they support node first

Comment: I tried that, but MongoDB only works if I start the server initiation Mongodb in console(at least in my mac), not by MongoDB package, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're confusing between mongoDB database and Node.js application. 
You don't run a mongoDB IN Node.js, they are two different things and processes.

First of all you must have a mongoDB instance running on the machine.
[Here's](http://ijonas.com/software-development/nosql/398/) only one example to run it as a service on a Linux server.

Node.js is a server side environment that among other things can CONNECT to a mongoDB instance to store o retrieve data. You have to install it as well on your server.

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a Node.js module that "mediates" the connection from a Node.js application to MongoDB and give you a set of utility to interact with your mongo database.